# Polling a webpage periodically

Tags: polling

I have a website where I need to poll a webpage in every minute or so. The page on the server will perform different task. I am trying to use Windows Scheduled Tasks, but that cannot be set to run in every minute. I know that there is cron jobs for this on Linux, but that is not available on Windows.

Any ideas how to do this on Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with windows service. It can be set to start when system is started up without the need for someone to log in. Also check this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/WindowsServiceScheduler.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The repeat interval drop-down goes down to 5 minutes here and I can easily type a 1 instead of the 5:

http://hypftier.de/temp/task.png

It gets this actually right, since when I click on OK, the description of the trigger reads:

http://hypftier.de/temp/task2.png

Or maybe that was added to Windows 7 or Vista, but I doubt it, actually.